# YandexMaps api возыращает 401 {"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"}

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Проект https://steklovozik.ru/#contact-section
Подключены яндекс карты, для отображения меток, и поиска адреса по клику на карте.Карта то работает то нет.
При клике на карту в форме заявки, на [запрос](https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_158228992118441435539&text=59.79362722708752%2C30.50639074218751&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&token=ghostery&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&origin=jsapi2Geocoder) возвращает ошибку
{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized"}

Ключ не заблокирован. Карта временами работает: потом перестает, потом снова работает. Бесплатный тариф. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В вашем примере запроса нет ключа, зато есть интересный параметр: "&token=ghostery". Скорее всего, это одноименное расширение для браузера модифицирует запрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Именно в аддоне Ghostery и была проблема.